# Restkit Basic Auth with http code 405

Tags: objective-c, ios, request, restkit

Im using the following code to a interface to login with basic http authentication.

```
  RKRequest *loginRequest = [[RKRequest alloc] initWithURL:URL];
  loginRequest.timeoutInterval = REST_LOGIN_TIMEOUT;
    loginRequest.username = username;
    loginRequest.password = password;
    loginRequest.authenticationType = RKRequestAuthenticationTypeHTTPBasic;
    loginRequest.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
    loginRequest.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response) {
        // blabla
    }

    ....sending request...
```

The first time I login, it just works. But if I do the same request again, I get a HTTP status code 405. When Im restarting my app, the next request works again. So I think it saves automatically some data like a session token or something internally. How can I reset this? Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does indeed store any cookies (including session cookie) automatically from responses. To clear this, use the following:

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookieStorage.cookies)
{
    [cookieStorage deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

You can of course first inspect the cookies to see wether you want to delete them or not.

Comment: I will try that and give u a feedback. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to use the NSHTTPCookieStorage method because RestKit already got a build in method for this. Use loginRequest.requestCache.storagePolicy = RKRequestCachePolicyNone; to prevent the headers from being saved in the cache.

Comment: I will try that, flashfabrixx. Thank you

Comment: Unlike iOS, cookies are shared among all applications in Mac. So I don't think clearing cookie(s) is really the best idea in this case.